# Strange Behaviour With The onkeydown Event in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, element, undefined-behavior

I am building a website at the minute which has an input text field where you can type markdown for your blog post, and I wanted the site to show a preview of the result (I am using the `Remarkable` JS library for the rendering process). I am currently using the `onkeydown` event in my element so that whenever a keyboard button is pressed, my JavaScript code will fire, and modify the contents of a `div` which is the output window.

The HTML code would look similar to:

```
<textarea onkeydown="render();" placeholder="type Markdown here to see the output as HTML" id="text"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

and then the JS behind this (excluding the `Remarkable` instantiation and configuration - I will be using `md` as my Remarkable object - If my terminology is wrong I am sorry as I am new to JS):

```
function render(){
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    var in = document.getElementById("text").value
    var html_output = md.render(in); // convert markdown to HTML
    out.value = html_output;
}
```

This is simple enough, but when I run the program, the markdown output seems to fall *behind* the input, like this:

```
===== INPUT - the text box =====
Hello world!
```

```
===== OUTPUT - the div =====
Hello world
```

Where, as you can clearly see, the output is lagging behind the input. From my knowledge, this shouldn't happen - or is this some unexplained behaviour of the `onkeydown` event - perhaps it fires before the character is inserted, causing me to have to implement a delay?

Comment: onkeydown is triggered prior to the input being added.  You can get the key pressed with something like event.keyCode.  Alternatively you could add a delay or use onkeyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `input` event. `oninput="render();"` this will capture the text as it's typed.